# ProgressDialog won't show, even in onPreExecute of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-intent, show, android-asynctask, progressdialog

In my class, Main extends Activity, I've this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case ...
    case CREDENTIAL_VIEW:
        new SetStatusProgressBar(this).execute();
```

And there is this nested class:

```
private class SetStatusProgressBar extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Main ctx;

    public SetStatusProgressBar(Main ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    }

    // progress dialog to show user that contacting server.
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, null,
                "Refreshing data from server...", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        //...
        //statements that refresh UI
        //...

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            timerProgressBarStop();
        }
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        //...
        //statements to download data from server
        //...
        return true;
    }

}
```

In the Main class I open a second Activity, in this way:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main.this, Credentials.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, CREDENTIAL_VIEW);
```

That second Activity returns to the Main activity in this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

I don't understand why when I navigate from the second Activity to the Main, the ProgressDialog will show ONLY AFTER that the UI refreshes... In this way the Progress Dialog stays on the screen only for half second... and then hides! :( I'd like to see the ProgressDialog on top during all the download time!

Help, please.
Thank you all

Comment: Are you performing any other operations within `case CREDENTIAL_VIEW:`, after you call `new SetStatusProgressBar(this).execute();`?

Comment: Do you start the second activity after launching the progress dialog? In this case of cause it will be hidden since it's running in the context of the Main. Try to use Application context. Or hide progress before launching the second activity and show it again on it's finished.

Comment: @ ackio: No, I don't start the second activity after launching the progress dialog. The progress dialog is launched ONLY when the second activity returns.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, first of all use getApplicationContext() instead of ctx variable. Using 'this' is not for good memory citizens.
Try updating progressDialog in onProgressUpdate(...) method.

Comment: `this` and `getApplicationContext()` are not strictly the same thing. Also using `this` (correctly) doesn't change memory footprint at all.

Comment: Well, in this case there are 2 activities and using getApplicationContext() might help here, because we do not need to bind it strictly to Credentials.class context.

Comment: how can I update progressDialog in the onProgressUpdate(...)? Which method should I call?

Comment: I think it is possible that way: @Override protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) { super.onProgressUpdate(values); if( !dialog.isShowing()){ dialog.show(); }}

Comment: Thanks 4 your help, but no luck. I've resolved with a workaround: I've shifted all the code with the connection to the server, in the second class, before returning in the main (that now contains only the statement for refreshing the UI).